# First Row As Column Header in OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
select * from OpenRowset('MSDASQL',
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; 
DefaultDir=C:\;
Extended properties=''ColNameHeader=True;
Format=Delimited(\tab);''',
'select * from MyFile.txt')
```

The issue is, the first row from the file becomes the header of the table.
What should I add/modify so that the first row from the file will not be the header?
ColNameHeader=False --> will not solve the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM 
 OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
 'Data Source=C:\;
 Extended Properties="Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"')...[FILE#txt]` 
 This one solves the problem :D

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use a `schema.ini` file, which should reside in the same directory as the file you're reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

That will allow you to specify your column names.